# Unable to update an username in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Unable to update an username in wordpress .This is what i have tried

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_login' => "abc123" ) ) ;
```

Comment: What you find after this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to update username:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_login' => 'abc123'), array('ID' => $user_id));
```

Comment: i tried this, it's working but logout the user automatically after update

Comment: Yes it's works perfectly on my end wp_update_user() is a direct function from wordpress but you can also do like this.

Comment: If you change username or password of user then he logged out.

Comment: yes.that is due to wordpress,but you have any alternate solution then that will helpful

Comment: Right now i don't have alternate solution for this but i will let you know if found solution.

Comment: i appreciate your answer ,thank you for your valuable effort.i am giving your answer a upvote .

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This should be like this. Please read this and apply it. it will help us.

Function - user_login

Reference - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

[image]

Comment: Hello, Downvoter, Can you describe why you down voted ?

Comment: thank you,this is really helpful. i think i should go through wordpress documentation

Comment: This is helpful! I don't see current doc contains this explanation
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/

Answer (score -2):

There might be a cache problem, check if is_wp_error( $user_id ) true or false, if no error try with email id instead i.e.

```
wp_update_user( array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'user_email' => $_POST[ 'user_email' ]
   ) );
```

Comment: ya its working but in case of user_login it is not working you can follow th below link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Comment: It should be 'user_email' as per wordpress standard. If this is a solution to your question, please mark it as the right answer!!

Comment: i have a form having multiple fields like username,email,mobile password for user profile in front end . i have to give the access to the user to update all the field .. i appreciate your answer but that i did for email field ,now i want to update username also.
wordpress does not allow to update user_login for better reference you can see @ranjit pradhan's post below